# PDO Select Statement

Tags: php, pdo

was hoping someone could give me some help... I'm using PDO to get some data from a database, but every time the script runs it comes back with no errors but won't display the required data, I KNOW that the data I'm looking for is in there too.. any help would be appreciated, this is what I have at the moment, thanks.

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Utils\\PDF_Utils\\PDF2Word\\details.sqlite');

    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr><td>FileID</td>
              <td>File Name</td>
              <td>Email From</td>
              <td>CC</td> <td>Subject</td>
              <td>File Size</td></tr>";


              $contents = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE fileName = 
                         '$yourFileName'");
              $contents->execute();

                   foreach($contents as $row) {
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['FileID'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['fileName'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['emailFrom'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['CC'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['fileSize'] . "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE fileName = ?"); 
$stmt->execute(array($yourFileName));
$contents = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

the rest is the same

Comment: 1. it does NOT the same thing. 2. to have non-blank screen you have to [setup your PDO and PHP properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: Fixed it now, thanks for the help anyway but done it a different way.

Answer (score -1):

Use a placeholder when preparing the statement and then execute the query passing the parameter, like this:

```
$contents = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE fileName = ?");
$contents->execute(array($yourFileName));
```

Then fetch the results using FETCH_ASSOC:

```
while($row = $contents->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     //your code here;
}
```

Comment: It should be `array($yourFileName)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 missed that. Fixed.

Comment: @DanielMorgan are you sure your database and tables are ok and that there is no error?

Comment: Yep I am very sure, because what I'm doing is creating a system so that if a user sends an e-mail with a .pdf attachment to a specific e-mail address it will store the details of that e-mail in a sqlite database, and I know it's storing because it shows the details on the first page but not the second...

Comment: @DanielMorgan Do actually your code's table name and fields name match your database's table and fields name's case (uppercase/lowercase)?

Answer (score -1):

put brackets around $yourFileName as {$yourFileName}